# A clarification on why isn't this question closed as not belonging to biology as science

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I am sharing a screen shot of a question I found on biology.se some time back requesting the name of the TV series from the OP's description of animated characters.

[image: the screenshot]

I was expecting this question to be closed as not belonging to biology as science. But on the other end, this question was well received with a good enough number of upvotes in quite a less time as I had observed and it was answered at the end.

This begs me to the question, Am I missing something obvious as to why this question was not closed and if I am, Can some explain me what is it?

This question is found [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/what-is-the-name-of-this-series) on bio.se webpage, if someone needs. Thanks for the time.

Comment: I agree. It is off topic.

Comment: @WYSIWYG thanks for clarifying.

Comment: By a stretch - this might be seen as a question about teaching biology, which [may be on-topic](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3162/questions-about-teaching-biology-off-limits).

Comment: @fileunderwater Thanks for the comment and I gladly agree with your opinion on "how to teach specific concepts in a field" type of questions as most users of the community belong to academia and can give their best opinions/advices in those matters. But this particular question as you said is quite a bit of stretch from that.

Comment: It is off-topic. I, personally, avoid closing questions that have a good answer, but that's certainly not the norm here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered that question as I think it serves an educational purpose on Biology and I think it is therefore on topic here.

Answer (score 0):

The description of this site states:

> Biology Stack Exchange is for people studying biology at any level.
>   Questions are from students, academics and active researchers in
>   biology and closely related fields, *including*:
>
> • general questions about biological concepts
>
> • questions about the biological mechanisms behind medical conditions
>
> • questions about techniques in a biological or biochemical laboratory

The devil, unfortunately, is in the ‘including’, which means these are just examples, allowing the subjective interpretation. *I* think that shown by @AliceD is overtolerant, but that is just my subjective opinion. Clearer guidelines would be good, but I don’t imagine we are likely to agree on them.